# Call original method from spy

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a service object, looking something like this:

```
class Service
  def call
    do_something if anything
  end

  private

  def do_something
    # do something
  end
end
```

I want to test that `do_something` is called under certain circumstances.

I tried to write something like this:

```
RSpec.describe Service do
  it 'calls do_something' do
    service = instance_double(Service)
    service.stub(:do_something)
    expect(Service).to receive(:new).and_return service
    Service.new.call

    expect(service).to have_received(:do_something)
  end
end
```

Obviously that doesn't work, 'cause I didn't stub `call` method for `service`. However, if I use `service = instance_double('Service', call: true)` it doesn't call `call`, so `do_something` is never got called.

I'm looking for something like `allow(service).to receive(:call).and_call_original`, if it's possible (maybe with replacing `instance_double` with `object_double` which makes more sense in that case. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you have tried and seen that `and_call_original` only works on partial doubles
so trying to use it with other types of doubles is not possible as the documentation says.

if we have a closer look at the partial double [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/basics/partial-test-doubles) we can see the `partial double` is described as:

```
A partial test double is an extension of a real object in a system that is instrumented with
test-double like behavior in the context of a test. This technique is very common in Ruby
because we often see class objects acting as global namespaces for methods. For example,
in Rails:

person = double("person")
allow(Person).to receive(:find) { person }
In this case we're instrumenting Person to return the person object we've defined whenever
it receives the find message. We can also set a message expectation so that the example
fails if find is not called:

person = double("person")
expect(Person).to receive(:find) { person }
RSpec replaces the method we're stubbing or mocking with its own test-double like method.
At the end of the example, RSpec verifies any message expectations, and then restores the
original methods.

Note: we recommend enabling the verify_partial_doubles config option.
```

above they said: `A partial test double is an extension of a real object`
that means doing `expect(Service.new).to receive(:call).and_call_original` will be valid since we are making it on an partial double that is originally a real world object created and the expectation is set on it making it a partial double.
but if we do `expect(object_double(Service.new)).to receive(:call).and_call_original` that will not work since we are setting this expectation on a pure double which is a verifying double, not an extension of a real world object. which means in the partial double we are directly addressing a real world or a real system object, but in the pure double case we are talking to the double. That is based on the documentation analogy, which apply to other types of doubles not just to `object_double`.

if you check this [link](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation) in the documentation of the `and_call_original` method you will notice this phrase:

```
Use and_call_original to make a partial double response as it normally would
```

that makes sense because it makes response as it normally would and normally in the system we call the original method on the real object or class not on a double.

[NOTE] here you want to explicitly test `do_something` method which is a private method. as far as you are concerned you need only to test public methods and private methods should not be tested. since if the public method that uses the private method runs successfully that for sure means the private method is working as expected.

so to make sure that you train your `do_something` private method you need to make two contexts:

```
context 'when anything is true' do
  tests for call method goes here in this case
end

context 'when anything is false' do
  tests for call method goes here
end
```

that means if `anything` for example is a model that does `model.save` make sure to set expectation on the save method so in one context it returns `false` resulting in `do_method does` does not get executed. and in the other context `when true` make sure you set an expectation to make it return `true` so your `do_something` method gets called and executed which implicitly means it gets trained and if call test passes in this case that for sure means that `do_something` is working as intended.
to learn more about testing private methods you can watch this great [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M) by Sandi Matz.